# Best way to display 100k+ points on map

Tags: google-maps, graphics, maps, latitude-longitude

I have a dataset with several hundred thousand lat/long points. I would like to render these points on a map for info-graphic purposes (as small dots or something similar).

This is not something that necessarily has to be interactive, or rendered in a browser. It's okay if it's just an image.

I know that attempting this with markers and Google maps would be tough... any other tools out there that would generate this type of map? Preferably free/open source?

Or, do you have a method to make this work with something like Google maps? I don't want to use a marker clusterer... I need to be able to see all of the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short :)

- Download and fire-up [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)
- Add some background map (e.g. [OSM WMS layer](http://www.osm-wms.de/#info) from `http://129.206.228.72/cached/osm`)
- Have your data in a CSV file, in [WKT format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), and load it on top (using add delimited text layer)
- Save as image

[You might want to peek what stackexchange.com has on GIS, too.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/visualising-wkt-geometry-string-in-qgis/13282#13282?newreg=8d477a4960814877b18dff4a33f69e5a)

Comment: Thanks, so far this looks like a great tool.